# How to output the spark execution plan as a stage in the spark ui

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've got Zeppelin setup and I'm writing some jobs in a notebook. While running them, I found out that spark printed out the query execution plan in the DAG visualization of one of the jobs.

Like so:

[image: example]

How is that possible and how can I reproduce that myself?

Comment: Use the .explain(bool) method on the data frame/RDD

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: As I wrote - I'm wondering how I can achieve the output as above in the spark-ui. I'm not trying to do anything specific, I know I can get the execution plan in the output log. I'm just wondering how the output in the UI was achieved.